# Event binding in MooTools like jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, binding, mootools

Is there a way to assign a multiple event types in MooTools like jQuery?

```
Mootools:
$$('#id').addEvents({
    keyup: fn,
    click: fn
});

jQuery:
$('#id).bind('keyup click' ,fn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, through the powerful [implement](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class#Class%3aimplement):

```
Element.implement({
    fakeBind : function(evtsStr, callback){
        var events = evtsStr.split(' '), 
            i = 0, 
            l = events.length;
        for (; i < l; i++){
            this.addEvent(events[i], callback);
        }
    }
});

$$('div.myClass').fakeBind('click mouseleave', function(event){
    console.log(event.type);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/vq8FD/)**

Comment: That is ugly API for adding events. One of the reasons I can't stand jQuery, the API is illogical.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you :), however, the powerful of mootools is that it's easy to 'simulate' jQuery's API ugliness! :D

Answer (score 1):

Its not much, but have a look at this: http://ryanflorence.com/jquery-1-4-mootools-1-2-compared/#binding-multiple-events

In this article Jquery 1.4 and mootools 1.2 are compared, and they really look alike..

Im afraid i can't think of any way that mootools can do that..